# Separability in Metric Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a non-separable metric space. 
My question is the following: does there exist some $\epsilon > 0$ and some uncountable
subset $S$ of $X$ such that $d(x,y) > \epsilon $ for any $x, y \in S$?

The question has a positive answer if $X$ is a normed linear space, as it can be easily proved by using the fact that if $M$ is a linear subspace and $x_{0}$ is not in the closure of X, then for some $\delta > 0$, $\|x - x_{0}\| > 0$ for every x in $M$  (so that $\|x - \lambda x_0\| > \lambda \delta$ for every $\lambda > 0$ and every $x \in M$), and applying Hausdorff maximality principle.

I think the question has a negative in general, but I cannot find a counterexample.
Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Pick a maximal (with respect to inclusion) subset $S$ such that $d(x,y)\ge \epsilon$ holds for all $x,y\in S$. Such a maximal element exists by Zorn's lemma. Note that $S$ is an $\epsilon$-net for your space. If for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $S$ turns out to be countable,  then taking union over $\epsilon=1/n$ yields a countable dense subset of $X$.

Comment: Very simple and beautiful argument! Thank you very much!